# How to override GenericServlet?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

this is my code

```
public class hi extends GenericServlet{
    public void init(ServletConfig parm1){

    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletRequest res){
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        pw.println("hi");
    }
}
```

when i try to complier it:

```
hi.java:16: error: hi is not abstract and does not override abstract method service(ServletRequest,ServletResponse) in GenericServlet
public class hi extends GenericServlet{
       ^
hi.java:21: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
hi.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
                            ^
  symbol:   method getWriter()
  location: variable res of type ServletRequest
3 errors
```

I think i have already overrided `service` method of  GenericServlet,but complier does got it, confuse me lot...

Comment: did you even read the error message or the code you wrote before posting this?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson sorry...maybe I fell into a dark place, could you explain it in some detail. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second param of service method should be `ServletResponse`